# List for Wireshark (tshark) Payload Protocols

Tags: wireshark, tshark, wireshark-dissector

I am trying to do some decoding of some non-standard protocols using tshark and user DLTs using the interface described [here](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUserDLTsSection.html).

I found a list of payload protocols in the Wireshark UI (Analyze => Enabled Protocols (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>)), but cannot find the matching one word name that is required for a user_dlts command; some will merely swap out `-` for `_` but others add/remove words entirely.

Is there a way to get the actual names to be used from the UI or (preferably) a list of all the possible payload protocols out there?

Answer (score 2):

You can also list all the protocols using `tshark -G protocols`.  See the [tshark man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) for more information about the `-G` option.

If you're only interested in the [link layer types](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html), you can discover those that Wireshark supports by running `editcap -T`, although you'll probably have to cross-reference the output of `tshark -G protocols` to find the correct name to use in the User DLTs protocol table.

Comment: The man page says that the `-G` option only lists _abbreviations_ of the protocols you can specify. I'm not entirely sure what that sentence means, but I know that running that command doesn't give me exactly the list I need. In my particular situation, I need to decode LTE RRC messages, specifically a "lte-rrc.bcch.dl.sch" protocol message. The only thing that `tshark -G protocols` prints out that's close to that is `lte_rrc`, which obviously doesn't fully specify the protocol I need to decode. Any idea where you can find a "full" list of available protocols?

Comment: How to enable  protocol without gui?

Answer (score 0):

In the Wireshark <2.* UI:

```
Internals => Supported Protocols => Protocols Tab
```

That has a list of all the protocols in a correctable format

```
For Wireshark 2.*
View => Internals => Supported Protocols => Protocols Tab
```

Comment: This is actually only a list of filters, its a closer start, but not great.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.  The right-most column is the protocol filter name, which is what you need to use as the name of the *Payload protocol*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dig deep, download the source:

```
 git clone https://code.wireshark.org/review/wireshark
```

and inspect the c files in wireshark/epan/dissectors/ specifically the register_dissector commands

```
fgrep -RIis "register_dissector(" wireshark/epan/dissectors/
```

This is better than:

```
 array=("column-formats" "defaultprefs" "fields" "plugins" "currentprefs" "dissector-tables" "ftypes" "protocols" "decodes" "fieldcount" "heuristic-decodes" "values")
 for i in "${array[@]}"; do tshark -G $i | fgrep -i 'RRC.BCCH.FACH'; done
```